# RemoveFromSuperView not working on UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c

It seems like such a simple thing to remove a button from a view, but it is not working.

---

**MyViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly, getter = getMyButton) UIButton* myButton;

- (id) init;
- (id) getMyButton;

@end
```

---

**MyViewController.m**

```
#import "MyViewController.h"
@interface MyViewController ()
@end
@implementation MyViewController
@synthesize myButton = _myButton;

- (id) init
{
    if([super initWithNibName: nil bundle: nil])
    {
        _myButton = nil;
    }
    return self;
}

- (id) getMyButton
{
    if(!_myButton) _myButton = [self createMyButton];
    return _myButton;
}

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    UIButton* myButton = self.myButton;
    [self.view addSubview: myButton];
}

- (void) didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (UIButton*) createMyButton
{
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] init];        
    [button setTitle: @"My Button"
            forState: UIControlStateNormal];

    [button addTarget: self
               action: @selector(myAction:)
     forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    button.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 40);   
    return button;
}

- (void) myAction: (id) sender
{
    [self.myButton performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject: nil waitUntilDone: NO];
}
@end
```

---

But no luck. Clicking the button simply does nothing.

If it is not a problem of concurrency then maybe it is a memory management problem? Maybe it is just something daft, I don't know.

I tried putting the following line into the myAction method

```
NSLog(@"Test 1");
if(_startButton.superview) NSLog(@"Test 2");
```

Only 'Test 1' is logged. Perhaps that is a clue but what I don't know is why the button has no superview when it is added to view and is visible on the screen

**Additional information**

I don't know, if any of this is relevant, but maybe

- I just `updated Xcode` to the latest version from the developer program (it supported up to iOS version 7.0 before, now 7.1)
- I just started testing the app on an actual iPhone (I get the same problem testing with the simulator though)
- Around the same time as this problem I also noticed that NSLog function doesn't work inside AppDelegate applicationHasLaunched method

Thanks

Comment: Try creating the button with `[UIButton buttonWithType:]` instead of alloc/init.  UIButton is possibly a class family since there's no way to explicitly set buttonType.

Comment: This was the fix. Can you post it as a response so I can accept it as the correct answer? Thank you so much David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buttons are a class family and should be created with `[UIButton buttonWithType:]`

Answer (score 2):

You didn't set the action for that button.

Change your `createMyButton` method like:

```
- (UIButton*) createMyButton
{
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    [button setTitle: @"My Button"
            forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 40);
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    return button;
}
```

Also change `myAction` method like:

```
- (void)myAction:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [sender performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject: nil waitUntilDone: NO];
}
```

Comment: Oops I accidentally omitted that line from the post on here while I was stripping out some visual formatting stuff. Very sorry. I have edited the post

Comment: As for the second part of your answer I tried changing the sender parameter to type UIButton* but it made no difference. Changing the self.myButton to sender for the performSelectorOnMainThread is not possible because there may be two buttons on the view that need removing for example. And self.myButton and sender in this case are pointers to the same UIButton object anyway ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems overly complicated:

- Why do you need to lazy create the button?
- Why does it need to be readonly?
- Why do you need the performselector in your action?

I have taken the liberty to rewrite your code:

**Header file**

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIButton * button;
```

**Code file**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [self.button setTitle:@"MyButton" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.button.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:self.button];
}

-(void)myAction:(UIButton*)sender
{
    [sender removeFromSuperview];

}
```

Happy coding!

**Edit**

If you insist on going with your original code, try changing

```
- (id) getMyButton
```

to

```
-(UIButton*)myButton
```

Comment: I used the lazy loading pattern because it is a dynamic form and depending on what the user does the controls which are shown may vary. In this case I could get away with pre-loading every control just in case it is needed but it is not a scalable solution and still doesn't explain why my code isn't currently working.

I made it readonly because there is no need for a setter when I can access the instance variable directly from within the same class.

I used the performSelector method just to rule out any concurrency issues for the problem after looking for an answer on here first.

Thanks

Comment: Events from the UI will always be delivered on the main thread. When using ARC it is in general a very good idea to access members though their property. Remember ARC is not a garbage collector. Memory management is handled compiletime, and ARC need to guess what's going on.

Comment: There is no need for a setter in this case because it is only ever 'set' using the instance variable (in the getter) and I would actually rather not expose a way for it to be changed from outside the class.. I guess the answer to the question 'Why does it need to be readonly' is 'Why does it need to be readwrite?' Thanks though, any idea why the original code doesn't work?

Comment: please see my edited answer above. As a general advise: The fewer lines of code you need to solve a given task, the fewer chances you have of making an error.

Comment: Personally I think that keeping logical correctness and logical integrity are better strategies for reducing errors than trying to do everything in as few lines as possible. Especially when it comes to scalability and maintainability. Maybe you can cut a few corners and reduce your line count but then when it comes to extending the functionality and those corners are needed you no longer have the logical integrity and things get messy. When I get back on my other laptop I will give the change a whirl and report back. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that your `myAction` is not get fired. Cause you forget to `addTarget`
on your `createMyButton` method just add one more line

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Oops I accidentally omitted that line from the post on here while I was stripping out some visual formatting stuff. Very sorry. I have edited the post

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** You've also marked this question as iOS but you are importing OSX headers

```
#import "NSViewController.h"
@interface MyViewController: NSViewController
```

you should be inheriting from UIViewController

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
```

Are you creating the view controller via the init code you've posted?

```
- (id) init
{
    if([super initWithNibName: nil bundle: nil])
    {
        _myButton = nil;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Here you are not allocating anything to `self` the code should be

```
- (id) init
{
    self = [super initWithNibName: nil bundle: nil];
    if(self)
    {
        _myButton = nil;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: I can't wait to get back on my other laptop and try out the 'self =' fix. I will report back when I do and fingers crossed mark as the correct answer :) it looks very hopeful. As for the UIViewController vs NSViewController; it actually inherits from a custom class 'VCPage' which is a subclass of UIViewController (and also imports UIKit). When I was isolating the code to post on here I substituted VCPage for NSViewController instead of UIViewController by mistake. Great catch.